# MDX to show Measure property

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I'm familiar with how to get member properties into an MDX result-set: create a calculated member using WITH.

The problem is when the member whose properties I want is a *measure*, not a dimension member.  Because the calculated member is created on the Measures hierarchy, I get the dreaded "The Measures hierarchy already appears in the Axis0 axis" error.  Here's the query I'm running:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.MeasureType AS  
Measures.CurrentMember.Properties('MEMBER_TYPE')
SELECT
MeasureType ON 0,
Measures.Members on 1
FROM TheCube
```

What I'm after is simply a list of all the measures ON 1 (this works, in itself); but with the measure's MEMBER_TYPE showing as the one column ON 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have members from the same hierarchy on both axes. There are two ways to get rid of this error.

**1. Create the calculated member on some other dimension**

```
WITH MEMBER [SomeDimension].[SomeHierarchy].MeasureType AS  
Measures.CurrentMember.Properties('MEMBER_TYPE')

SELECT
[SomeDimension].[SomeHierarchy].MeasureType ON 0,
Measures.Members on 1
FROM [TheCube]
```

**2. Have them in a set and not on different axes.**

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.MeasureType AS  
Measures.CurrentMember.Properties('MEMBER_TYPE')

SELECT
{Measures.MeasureType, Measures.Members} ON 0
FROM [TheCube]
```

Discarding the second method as it gives a static value. What's really needed is a cross-tab value. So sticking with first method.

Comment: Thanks.  The set solution (2) gives me a dimensionality not matching error, but your solution (1) works.
It never occurred to me to put this calculated member on another dimension.  It seems really bizarre, when the dimension has nothing to do with the query itself.
I guess it doesn't matter which dimension I use, as long as it has ALL as a default member?  Or will any dimension at all do the job?

Comment: Just out of curiosity- can you paste the error message text for the first solution?

Comment: My mistake.  I tried your solution (2) but added the calculated member to another dimension instead of to Measures.  The error was the wonderfully useful "Query (3, 1) Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function".  (If you're in a chatty mood - why are MDX error messages so useless, with a clear unfilled placeholder?)
But when I corrected, it returns just a single column for calculated member Measures.MeasureType, UNIONed with the set of all Measures, on the columns axis - whereas I'm trying to get the MeasureType for each measure.

Comment: I see what happened. What its giving is a single value. But what you needed was this value against every measure. Solution 2 is not going to help in this case.

Comment: On **why MDX error messages are so useless** I think roadplan of MS is to slowly stop supporting MDX(sad as it is) and promote DAX. So probably it's not improving these small things. But with a solid understanding of set theory mixed with lots of head-scratchings and hard-practice, they slowly start making sense :)

Comment: Re MDX vs DAX. That's bad news!  I've always liked MDX and wanted to get better at it, precisely because I like set theory.  I was put off in SQL2005 by the terrible infrastructure (editor, lack of doco, ambiguous error messages).  Seems things have got better, but not much.

Comment: People are still using Windows XP in the age of Windows 10. So don't hold your breath on when MDX is going to die. There would always be a lot of companies which can't pay for huge RAM or just don't see too much value in upgrading their servers. For them multi-dimensional SSAS would always be the preferred option. But it definitely looks like the mainstream companies would soon start riding on tabular models. And then there is "Big data" :)